# Size of compressed files on disk increases massively after I sort?

Tags: pandas, compression, parquet

I have a pandas dataframe that I store on disk as a GZIP. On RAM its around 90GB, and when I saved it as gzip using pandas.to_parquet, it compresses to around 3GB.

I recently sorted it using pandas.sort_values on a different column, and all of the sudden this size on disk when I save it using the same method is 60GB.

Why is that happening and is there a different method of sorting / saving to prevent this?

Comment: gzip looks for string repetitions in a 32 KB window. If your repetitive strings are too far apart, they will not be recognized and so won't compress well. You can try the `brotli` method, that should be able to use a window of up to 16 MB, although I have no idea what parameters pandas is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have to guess that your file was previously sorted on a different column, and that matches of the contents of that column with immediately preceding records was an important part of the compression. Then when you sorted on a different column, that other column was effectively randomized so that similar values were no longer near each other. The column you sorted will likely have better compression than before, but that effect is small compared to the originally sorted column. That's what killed the compression.

Comment: this still blows my mind though. How come its cheaper to store the location of similar values than just storing the value itself?

Comment: Not similar values, but similar _strings_. If the string is long enough, a reference to a previous occurrence of the same string (a length and a distance) will take fewer bits than the string itself. This can be true for string lengths as short as three.